# CakePhP mailer not sending mails to gmail (but sending Ok to outllook)

Tags: email, cakephp, gmail

So the problem looks like my domain is being blacklisted by google, but when I check in spamhaus.org I see no issues with the domain. Also if I send mails using the webmail of my mail supplier I receive the mails ok. So the symptoms again are:

- Server sending mails Ok to Outlook users but Gmail users are not receiving them
- The mails are being sent with NO ERRORS from the server
- When I send mails from the webservice of my supplier gmail users DO receive the mails

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the same problem:

The username in the EmailTransport configuration in app.php:

```
 'EmailTransport' => [
        'default' => [
            'className' => 'Smtp',
            // The following keys are used in SMTP transports
            'host' => 'smtp.whatever.es',
            'port' => 587,
            'timeout' => 30,
            'username' => 'user@domain.com',
            'password' => 'password',
            'client' => null,
            'tls' => true,
            'url' => env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null),
```

Must be the same as the "setFrom" in the UserMailer sending function:

```
class UserMailer extends Mailer
{
    public function welcome($user)
    {
        $url = Router::url(['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'setPassword', $user->id, '_full' => true]);
        
        $this
            ->setTo($user->email)
            ->setFrom('user@domain.com', 'TheWeb')
            ->setSubject('Welcome to TheWeb')
            ->setViewVars(['content' => 'Hi, your user has been created. To access you must click the '
                . 'next link: <a href="' . $url . '">' . $url . '</a>']) 
            ->setTemplate('default')         
            ->setEmailFormat('html');
    }
```

Otherwise Google will tag the mail as dangerous and it will not be sent or will be tagged as spam.